# hide checkbox if textbox has text, jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

When the document loads I am trying to css hide a check box only if a textbox has text.   Instead all the check boxes are being hidden, even if the text boxes are empty.  Any help please

```
    $(document).ready(function () {


            //if statements to disable the fill checkboxes if there are dates already filled
            if ($("#<%=FinishDateSrvcTXT.ClientID%>").text != "") {
                $("#<%=FinishFillCHK.ClientID%>").css('display', 'none');
            }

            if ($("#<%=startdateSrvcTXT.ClientID%>").text != "") {
                $("#<%=StartFillCHK.ClientID%>").css('display', 'none');
            }

            if ($("#<%=FinishDateBodyShopTXT.ClientID%>").text != "") {
                $("#<%=FillFinishBodyShopCHK.ClientID%>").css('display', 'none');
            }
            if ($("#<%=StartDateBodyShopTXT.ClientID%>").text != "") {
                $("#<%=FillStartBodyCHK.ClientID%>").css('display', 'none');
            }
            if ($("#<%=CompleteDatedetailTXT.ClientID%>").text != "") {
                $("#<%=CompleteFilldetailCHK.ClientID%>").css('display', 'none');
            }

            if ($("#<%=startdatedetailtxt.ClientID%>").text != "") {
                $("#<%=startdatedetailCHK.ClientID%>").css('display', 'none');
});
```

Comment: use `.val()` insead of `.text`

Comment: how do you define "text"? is this the value? the text after the input type checkbox? You use <input></input>? a label?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `if` statements to use `val()`.

```
$("#<%=FinishDateSrvcTXT.ClientID%>").val().length > 0){
   $("#<%=FinishFillCHK.ClientID%>").css('display', 'none');
}
```

Comment: Noticed it just before you commented :D. Essentially, you use `val()` to get the value in the textbox instead of `text`.

Answer (score 1):

Hm, try

```
 function check() {
 if(document.getElementById('yourTextFieldId').text != null) {
 document.getElementById('yourCheckboxId').disabled = true;
 }
 else {
 document.getElementById('yourCheckboxId').disabled = false;
 }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use something like this:

```
$('input:checkbox').each(function () {
    if (!this.value || !$(this).text() ) $(this).hide();
});
```

here it will hide each checkbox as soon as there is no value or no text.