# Jquery if textbox>0

Tags: jquery, syntax-error

So i'm terrible are js, and i'm trying to get a jquery script, to onblur check if the text box has content, and if it does then proceed with the script, this is what i have

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#embed").blur(function (){
            $("#embed").val().length > 0){
                $("#fade").fadeIn(1000);olink = $("#embed").val(); 
                $("#oembed").oembed(olink, {
                    embedMethod: "append", 
                    maxWidth: 300, 
                    maxHeight: 150 
                });
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

but i'm getting a syntax error(dreamweaver) on the line that reads

> $("#embed").val().length > 0){

any suggestions would be great... thanks

Comment: The ) after your 0 is unmatched

Comment: I'm very sad none of the answers so far have attempted to demonstrate a "more better" way of writing this code. That above is a mess.

Comment: I'm very sad none of your teachers never told you "more better" is incorrect... never the less i did say that i was "terrible with js" and i am learning... I don't care if it's a mess... i understand what i have there and it works... someone should have told you there are plenty of different ways to code... it's all down to Preference and habit but thank you for commenting

Comment: I did add an answer; I was sad that the other participants didn't see fit to make a more substantial effort. It's up to you how you handle your code; it's up to me to advocate best practices I know are beneficial. And "more better" is proper english, if you're a character on Good Times... `;)`

Comment: sorry as i stated i am terrible at js... i don't know what that means... i did attempt to mess with the parenthesis and brackets before posting, but to no success, your solution might work but i'm giving this one to JakeRow123 for putting it in terms a newb to js like me can under stand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what your code should look like (*in my opinion*, of course), properly formatted:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $embed = $("#embed"),
        $fade = $('#fade'),
        $oembed = $('#oembed'),
        oembed = {
            embedMethod: "append",
            maxWidth: 300,
            maxHeight: 150
        },
        olink;

    $embed.blur(function(){
        if ($embed.val().length){
            $fade.fadeIn(1000);

            olink = $embed.val(); 
            $oembed.oembed(olink, oembed);
        }
    });
});
```

What was wrong with the code you posted, other than the messy cluster of confusion? Your `if()` wasn't... there. You left `if(` out:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#embed").blur(function (){
        $("#embed").val().length > 0){
```

Can you see it? Kinda hard to differentiate those three lines. Now look at the code above, which...

1. Properly uses selector caching (`var $embed = $("#embed")`).
2. Uses `var` to declare all variables, separated by a `,` so they're all local; also...
3. Makes `olink` a proper non-global-scoped variable (and hey, still works due to closures, how nifty).
4. Moves the `oembed` object (which I created from that `{}` being passed as an argument) into a proper variable, cleaning the code up and also caching it.

I think it's legitimately easier to read and spot problems if you take care when formatting your code and decide to use best practices like caching and non-global variables. The `if(` was the immediate problem, but the code over all was in need of some attention and a little lovin' kindness.

Comment: @Luke, whether or not you agree with my delivery (which ok, was/is glib), take a moment to actually read what I wrote. I don't care if I get an upvote or whatever; the answer I provided literally was directed at providing you with something actually valuable, not just bandaiding what you had. I realize you're a newbie and know I made the [same mistakes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5724400/does-using-this-instead-of-this-provide-a-performance-enhancement) longer than I'd like to admit (closures used to baffle me). So, FWIW.

Answer (score 1):

You don't seem to have an if statement, try:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#embed").blur(function () {
        if($("#embed").val().length > 0) {
            $("#fade").fadeIn(1000);
            olink = $("#embed").val(); 
            $("#oembed").oembed(olink, {
                embedMethod: "append", 
                maxWidth: 300, 
                maxHeight: 150 
            });
         }
    });
});
```

### EDIT

You can make your code a little cleaner like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#embed").blur(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var embed_val = $this.val();
        if(embed_val.length) {
            $("#fade").fadeIn(1000);
            $("#oembed").oembed(embed_val, {
                embedMethod: "append", 
                maxWidth: 300, 
                maxHeight: 150 
            });
         }
    });
});
```

Comment: Stellar, worked  fine, thank you... i was missing the if because (like i said) i'm terrible.. i seen another post(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8773630/hide-checkbox-if-textbox-has-text-jquery) on here that miss lead me

Comment: @Luke, there is a substantive difference when you habitualize yourself to well-considered code conventions. In this case, it would have made it easier to spot your problem. That's why it's a "best practice", but it's not a mandate.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#embed").blur(function (){
    if ($("#embed").val().length > 0){
      $("#fade").fadeIn(1000);
      olink = $("#embed").val(); 
      $("#oembed").oembed(olink, {
        embedMethod: "append", 
        maxWidth: 300, 
        maxHeight: 150 
      });
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

That should do the trick.